# H2O in R - Automatic Data Processing

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, h2o

I notice that the H2O [packages mentions that it](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3175/docs-website/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepLearning_Vignette.pdf):

> preprocesses the data to be standardized for compatibility with the
>   activation functions (recall Table 1’s summary of each activation
>   function’s target space). Since the activation function does not
>   generally map into the full spectrum of real numbers, R, we first
>   standardize our data to be drawn from N (0, 1). Standardizing again
>   after network propagation allows us to compute more precise errors in
>   this standardized space, rather than in the raw feature space. For
>   autoencoding, the data is normalized (instead of standardized) to the
>   compact interval of mathcalU(−0.5, 0.5), to allow bounded activation
>   functions like Tanh to better reconstruct the data.

However, I don't fully understand. My impression was ([here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/), and [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/01/01/how-to-standardize-data-for-neural-networks.aspx)) that the the **categorical variables should be broken into 1-of-C dummies and the continuous data normalised**. **Then, everything should be standardised to [-1,1]**.

I also don't see a way of specifying the neurons for the read-out layer. I thought that if we have a **categorical** output variable then we want to use softmax activation function (and encode as 1-of-C) / if we have a **continuous** output (e.g. price) then we scale that to [-1,1] and use 'tanh' / if we have a **single binary** output then we can use logistic and code it as [0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classification and regression (i.e., supervised mode), H2O Deep Learning does the following:

The input into the first neural network layer is indeed 1-of-C dummies (either 0 or 1) for categorical features. Continuous features are standardized (not normalized): de-meaned and scaled by 1/variance.

For regression, the response variable is also standardized internally, to allow the (single) output neuron's activation value to be compared against it. However, for presentation to the user during scoring, the predictions are de-standardized into the original space.

For classification, we use Softmax to get probabilities for the C classes, even for binary classification.

The documentation you cited also refers to unsupervised autoencoding (by enabling the autoencoder flag). In that case, the input is normalized (i.e., scaled by 1/(max-min)) instead of being standardized. That is needed to allow the auto-encoder to have fully overlapping input and output spaces.

Comment: Thanks very much! Is it not the case that it is more effective to scale binary inputs as (-1,1) - centred near the origin, and likewise for categorical by using e.g.: urban = (0 1), suburban = (1 0), and rural = (-1 -1)? Or does having a bias unit mean that the effects coding (-1 for the omitted) is equivalent to standard 1-of-(C-1) coding? Further, since the the continuous features are only standardized then does that not mean we have one input with a range of 0 to 1 and another with range of 0 to 1,000,000 which results in it 'contribution' over-powering the tiny (0,1)?

Comment: I was just getting at this bit "If you know that some inputs are more important than
others, it may help to scale the inputs such that the more important ones
have larger variances and/or ranges" from the neural-nets/part2/ FAQ As it appears that normalising the continuous inputs will give them a range of e.g. (-10,10) compared to the categorical (0,1) and thus more importance in the neural network? Whereas if they are normalised to (0,1) also, so all our inputs are (0,1) then this seems to contradict that using (-1,1) is more effective. Thanks! Confused.

Comment: sorry one last thing: is it the case that the normalisation method used depends on the activation functions in the hidden layer? To minimise the bias we want to use a range that falls within the input to the activation function that produces a non-flat gradient? So tanh has a wider range than sigmoid and ReLU has a wider range than tanh? So for ReLU we want to have input > 0? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

H2O achieves the effect of 1-of-C dummy encoding, without the cost.  The exact details vary by algorithm, but there's always an obvious algorithmic optimization that gives the predictive strength of a dummy encoding, without the memory or speed costs.

Cliff